# java/android: editing an object after clone/duplicate also edits the original

Tags: java, android, clone

I "cloned" an object with two different strategies. CloneConstructor and clone method. (Code below)
after editing the cloned objects, the "original" object is also edited.
What am i doing wrong?

My custom object

```
public class FormData {

    HashMap<String, Object> values; 
    String stgFormInstanceId, requestId, stgFormDatenTransfer;

    // Constructor for creating data with WebService
    public FormData(SoapObject so, StgForm form) {....}

    // Constructor for creating new data
    public FormData() {....}

    // clone Constructor
    public FormData(FormData oldData) {
        this.requestId = oldData.requestId;
        this.stgFormDatenTransfer = oldData.stgFormDatenTransfer;
        this.stgFormInstanceId = oldData.stgFormInstanceId;
        this.values = oldData.values;
        this.toString();
    }

    // Clone Method
    public FormData cloneFormData() {
        FormData newData = new FormData();
        newData.requestId = this.requestId;
        newData.stgFormDatenTransfer = this.stgFormDatenTransfer;
        newData.stgFormInstanceId = this.stgFormInstanceId;
        newData.values = this.values;
        newData.toString();
        return newData;
    }

    public void addValue(String key, Object value) {
        this.values.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

my Activity:

```
public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private static HashMap<String, StgField> fields;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private FormData data;
    private FormData editedData;
    private String instanceId, requestId;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private static ViewMode viewMode;
    private static ArrayList<EditText> editTextList;
    private StgForm currentForm;
    private Context context;
    private FormData editedData2;
    private FormData editedData3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    data = ....;
    }

    private void editTicket() {
        setViewMode(ViewMode.edit);

        editedData2 = new FormData(data);
        editedData3 = data.cloneFormData();

        setEditabilityOfFields(fields, true);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }

    private void saveTabValues(int position) {

        ArrayList<StgField> fields = getFieldsOfTAB(position);
        for (StgField field : fields) {
            View view = field.getViewItem();

            if (view instanceof EditText) {
                EditText et = (EditText) view;
                String fieldName=field.getFieldName();
                Editable value = et.getText();
                String s = value.toString();

                try {
                    editedData2.addValue(fieldName,
                            s);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                try {
                    editedData3.addValue(fieldName,
                            s);
                } catch (Exception e) {}                
            }
        }
        System.out.println(data.toString());
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println(editedData2.toString());
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println(editedData3.toString());
    }
}
```

Now, after calling editTicket() and then saveTABvalues() in my Activity, all three objects 
 *data* / *editData2* / *editData3* are the same. This is ok for editData2 and editData3, but I dont understand, why "data" has also changed...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are transferring the data from "data" in  public FormData(FormData oldData); in editTicket(); So whenever you edit Edit2 or Edit3 you will also change data's original values. You'll need to use clone() in your clone method, or new Object(oldObject) whenever applicable, like String s = new String(oldString);

Edit:

When I say "transfer" I mean you are just assigning a reference to the original value. So you are not creating  a nw value in yuour public FormData(FormData oldData);

Comment: Thanks for yout reply, but I dont undestand. In the public FormData cloneFormData() I do create a new object, fill it with the actual values and return it. Doesn't the public FormData(FormData oldData) Constructor creates a new object by itself? I mean, its a constructor...

Answer (score 0):

stupid me...
I have to do

```
// clone Constructor
public FormData(FormData oldData) {
    requestId = new String(oldData.requestId.toString());
    stgFormDatenTransfer = new String (oldData.stgFormDatenTransfer.toString());
    values = new HashMap<String,Object>(oldData.values);        
}
```

Just didnt create **new** attributes with **= new String(...);**

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote: `[...] new Object(oldObject) whenever applicable, like String s = new String(oldString);[...]`. But I'm glad you figured it out.